# How to create a trustore in jks format?

Tags: ldap, ssl-certificate, openldap, truststore

I am integrating one of our services with ldap authentication and having issues creating a TrustStore which is required as a parameter in the service configuration. I am a newbie and not much familiar with TLS.

I have a crt bundle which gandi provided for our domain. lets say gandi.crt, which I see has three certificates.
And I have certificate from my ldap server which I got using

```
echo -n | openssl s_client -connect ldap.abc.com:636 | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > /tmp/abc.chain.pem
```

How do I create a TrustStore using this files or am I missing any files to proceed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: With the Java keytool.

Comment: can you share the command please